# How to make create Children permission false for all sub folders inside alfresco document library for all users

Tags: alfresco-share

My requirement is i don't want to allow any user to create or upload any folder or document inside all sub folders  of document library.
for this i need to make create children permission false.
So please tell me How to make create Children permission false for all sub folders inside alfresco document library for all users.

Please provide sample code snippet and steps to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you asking for a code snippet, why is simply defining appropriate permissions (then inheriting it down the document library) not an option?

Comment: Change the role of site for usergroup for which you don't want to allow create children permission.

Comment: Hi Krutik, Can you explain that how can i change the role of site for user group. I am quite new in alfresco, so not getting how to do this. i write some code in changePermission.js  but i am getting errors. So please provide steps and if possible, provide sample code snipet.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Lista, Actually i read some posts on forum, so i conclude that to hide create and upload option for non document library folder, i need ti make create permission false.  But i am  not getting what exactly should i do or where to do.  Thats why asking for help.   Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can create your own PermisionGroup.

Add in your projet your xml file definition :

```
main\amp\config\alfresco\module\mymodule\bootstrap\custom-sitePermissionDefinitions.xml

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE permissions >
<!-- Custom permissions-->
<permissions>
    <!-- Namespaces used in type references -->
   <namespaces>
      <namespace uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0" prefix="sys"/>
      <namespace uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0" prefix="cm"/>
      <namespace uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/site/1.0" prefix="st"/>
  </namespaces>

   <permissionSet type="st:site" expose="selected">
    <!-- Keep the existing -->
   <permissionGroup name="SiteManager" allowFullControl="true" expose="true" />

   <permissionGroup name="SiteCollaborator" allowFullControl="false" expose="true">
      <includePermissionGroup permissionGroup="Collaborator" type="cm:cmobject" />
   </permissionGroup>

   <permissionGroup name="SiteContributor" allowFullControl="false" expose="true">
      <includePermissionGroup permissionGroup="Contributor" type="cm:cmobject" />
   </permissionGroup>

    <permissionGroup name="SiteConsumer" allowFullControl="false" expose="true">
         <includePermissionGroup permissionGroup="Consumer" type="cm:cmobject" />
         <includePermissionGroup permissionGroup="ReadPermissions" type="sys:base" />
    </permissionGroup>

  <!-- Custom role based on the contributor one            -->
  <permissionGroup name="MyCustomRole" allowFullControl="false" expose="true" >
      <includePermissionGroup permissionGroup="Consumer" type="cm:cmobject"/>
       <!-- remove the permission to add a children
      <includePermissionGroup permissionGroup="AddChildren" type="sys:base"/>
      -->
      <includePermissionGroup permissionGroup="ReadPermissions" type="sys:base" />
  </permissionGroup>
```

Don't forget to declare it in your context file (**module-context.xml**) :

```
<!-- Registration of myproject ROLES -->
<bean id="myproject_permissionBootstrapSite" parent="permissionModelBootstrap">
  <property name="model" value="alfresco/module/${project.artifactId}/bootstrap/custom-sitePermissionDefinitions.xml"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Hi Akah, can you tell me the name of first xml file and location of both files.  i think context file i have to put in shared, extension folder. Just tell me the name of xml file in which we are witting custom permission and also tell me the location.   Thanks.

Comment: The name is module-context.xml at the root of my amp module : http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/dev-extensions-modules-module-context.html

Comment: Hi Akah, I created file with name custom-sitePermissionDefinitions.xml and placed in side Alfresco\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension\model, and i aulredy have custom-model-context.xml file inside Alfresco\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension, so i added   <bean id="myproject_permissionBootstrapSite" parent="permissionModelBootstrap">
  <property name="model" value="alfresco/extension/model/custom-sitePermissionDefinitions.xml"/>
 </bean>    this code in custom-model-context.xml   after clicking manage permission its giving error.

Comment: And the error message on server console is     org.alfresco.repo.security.authority.UnknownAuthorityException: 05020034 An authority was not found for GROUP_site_hr_MyCustomRole,    I am not getting whats wrong, Can you please help me with this.

Comment: It might be because the site you created was before the new Role. Can you try to create a new Site ?